# C# Syntax error while Trying to update Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I Am trying to update an Active Directory record to change the Manger.

I am using this code:

```
object managerDN = values[0].ManagerDN;
entryToUpdate.Properties["manager"].Value = managerDN;
```

The MangerDN looks like this:

```
"jdoe01,"CN=John Doe,OU=Programming Group,OU=InformationManagement,OU=Support Services,OU=Administrative Services,OU=VicePresident,OU=President,OU=Domain Users,DC=MyDoman,DC=net"
```

I have also tried:

```
"LDAP://jdoe01,"CN=John Doe,OU=Programming Group,OU=InformationManagement,OU=Support Services,OU=Administrative Services,OU=VicePresident,OU=President,OU=Domain Users,DC=MyDoman,DC=net"
```

When I run the program I get an e that states:

> Error messageinvalid dn Syntax has been specified.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You do seem to have some stray double quotes in there

Comment: Thanks @DavidG copied and pasted from a CSV file and they were left overs

Comment: So is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

The DNs you have are not correctly formatted. IIRC ADSI requires you to prefix the value with LDAP:// so you'll want something like this:

`LDAP://CN=John Doe,OU=Programming Group,OU=InformationManagement,OU=Support Services,OU=Administrative Services,OU=VicePresident,OU=President,OU=Domain Users,DC=MyDoman,DC=net`

Comment: @DavdiDesmond entryToUpdate.Properties["manager"].Value = "LDAP://"+"CN = John Doe, OU = Fleet Section,OU = Fleet Management & Facilities,OU = Administrative Services,OU = VicePresident,OU = President,OU = Domain Users,DC = orange - county - sheriff,DC = net";  But still does not work??